# Get field type of document field from firestore

Tags: python, google-cloud-firestore

Is it possible to get the field type of a field in a document?

I want to create a function that looks something like this:

```
def print_field_types(collection_ref, document_ref):
   db = some_function_that_initializes_app()
   document = db.collection(collection_ref).document(document_ref).get().to_dict()
   for field in document:
       print(f"Field_name : {field}, Field_type : {field.type}")
```

Where field.type returns the type of the field. For example it should return something like this:

```
Field_name : Username, Field_type : string
Field_name : Age, Field_type : number
Field_name : Tasks, Field_type : array
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the document snapshot, with `document.get` you can get the field value as an Object and then in Python from this object you can the get the type with `type()` function.